# Link with Name Attibute in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I was wondering about how i can do this in rails

because i want something like

```
<a href="requests/13#new">Comment!<a>
```

anyone knows it?

greetings

Comment: Could you clarify? Do you want to know how to do the "#new" part?

Comment: your answer was what i've been looking for... thank you so much

the question was about to use anchors links in rails...i'm not a natural english speaker, so i didn't know the word of that concept, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= link_to "Comment!", url_for(:controller => "requests", :action => "show", :id => 13, :anchor => "new") %>
```

If you are working with a Request object and a restful route.

```
<%= link_to "Comment!", request_path(@request, :anchor => "new") %>
```

More details are available in the [link_to helper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html).